# Angular local varable change detection

Tags: angular, onchange, angular-changedetection

I have a parent holding a variable 'value'and passing this variable with 2-way data binding to a child component. How can the parent be aware of any changes on this variable?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-control',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
export class Parent Component{
   value: string
}
```

and in parent html

```
<child-input-1-component [(value)]="value"></child-input-1-component>
```

The child component is an input, for simplicity i only put one but in the real app, i have several of this component that need to be displayed dynamically with ngSwitch.

Whenever the user types something in any of these child components I need the parent to call a function.

I could use @Output on every child but it does not look very elegant and besides the value is updated in real time on the parent, I just need to know when.

Is there something like "watcher" in angular that checks for value changes?

Comment: *I could use @Output on every child*: you already are. That's how 2-way data binding works. `[(value)]="value"` is just a shortcut notation for `[value]="value" (valueChange)="value = $event"`. So just add your function call there.

Comment: So i can i use it for this purpose? the value on the parent is updated correctly,but  i also need to call i function when this happen.

Comment: Yes, that's what outputs are for: notify the parent of an event from a child, and let the parent do what it needs to do when this event happens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am new to angular and not sure how to implement this, could you please provide me with a code example?

Comment: `[value]="value" (valueChange)="value = $event; doSomething()"`.

Comment: Thank you, i really appreciate your help, it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

[()] is **language sugar** ,[(what)] = [what] + (whatChange)